# Javascript - Detect the undefined object key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading

I am planning to create a `Resource` service in AngularJS and inject this one service in my directives for use. I am using `RequireJS` for my resolving. To use a resource then, I want to call `Resource.User` or `Resource.Client`.

Now, I want to be able to lazy load the services as the demand comes along. So, say in a directive, I inject my resource as

```
define(['app'], function(app){
    app.directive('myDirective', ['Resource', function(Resource){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<my-directive></my-directive>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr){
                Resource.User.get({id : 1}, function(response) {...});
            }
    }]); 
});
```

At this point, if this is the first call to `Resource.User`, I'd like to somehow inside the `Resource` service to resolve the service and return the information. So the first time, the resource would not have the object `User`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What would `Ressource.User` return then for the first call? I assume you want to load the User asynchronously?

Comment: Yes. `Resource.User` would then get assigned to Angular's `$resource`.